# Angular 2 tooltip only if css class is used

Tags: css, angular

I've a button with a label too long, so I created a class for ellipsis:

```
<button type="submit" title="{{'button.label' | translate}}"
 (click)="doSomething()">
    <span class="labelEllipsis">{{'button.label' | translate}}</span>
</button>
```

where labelEllipsis class is:

```
.labelEllipsis{
    text-overflow: ellipsis!important;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap; 
    display: block;
}
```

The problem is that tooltip is always shown, even if the label isn't truncate with ellipsis. My question is: is there a way to show tooltip only if label is actually truncated? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Title attribute is default to show the tool tip. You can create a directive or condition based attribute like if your char limit is over and above(your limit) then show the attribute or something like that will do.

`ng-attr-title="{{this[message]}}"`

this will help you to put condition based title..